# How can I choose between Client or Pool for node-postgres

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

From https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting , seems like we can choose between `Pool` or `Client` to perform query

```
pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})
```

---

```
client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  client.end()
})
```

---

Their functionalities look very much the same. But, the documentation doesn't explain much the difference between `Pool` and `Client`.

May I know, what thing I should consider, before choosing between `Pool` or `Client`?

Comment: have checked out the [environmental variables for PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html). I have somewhat of an idea what's the difference.

Comment: `Client` is one static connection. `Pool` manages a dynamic list/pool of `Client` objects, with automatic re-connect functionality ;) Normally, you would just create a single `Pool` object and use it ;)

Comment: Pool is recommended

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> May I know, what thing I should consider, before choosing between Pool or Client?

Use a pool if you have or expect to have multiple concurrent requests. That is literally what it is there for: to provide a pool of re-usable open `client` instances (reduces latency whenever a `client` can be reused).

In that case you definitely **do not want** to call `pool.end()` when your query completes, you want to reserve that for when your application terminates because `pool.end()` disposes of all the open `client` instances. (Remember, the point is to keep up to a fixed number of `client` instances available.)

Comment: Mine is a always running single instance background task. Should I use `Client` then, and end it when I finish my query?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng using a `client` directly should work fine then.

Comment: @user268396 This clears up some blurry lines in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: A better-worded answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451786/11224924

Answer (score 5):

One of the most significant differences to know, is that you must use `Client` when you use `transactions`.
From the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions):

> You must use the same client instance for all statements within a
> transaction. PostgreSQL isolates a transaction to individual clients.
> This means if you initialize or use transactions with the pool.query
> method you will have problems. Do not use transactions with the
> pool.query method.

Comment: yes, but you can create a client from a pool instance https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling#examples

Comment: @GViz not sure I'm getting your point. Pool is a set of clients. In order to perform a transaction (two or more queries) all the transactions queries must be executed on shared client. Using Pool can not guaranty providing the same Client.

Comment: That's right, I thought you were implying that only an instance of Client can be used.