# When to use node-postgres package pool vs client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I searched a lot about this , I am using the pool but do not know what is the difference between both?

```
    const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()
await client.connect()
const res = await client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'])
console.log(res.rows[0].message) // Hello world!
await client.end()
```

Comment: Client is a single connection to a postgres database server while a Pool can have multiple connections to a database server. When using Client, you have one connection that needs to shared in your code. You can't fire of two query with Clients at the same time. When using Pool, you ask the pool to query the records you need. The Pool decides which underlying connection/client to use. It is also possible to support multiple concurrent queries with Pool. You can also specify how long and how many connections a pool can have at any time. Hope that gives you some idea about their usage.

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned that this is a duplicate question... but the answer provided in this one is much clearer and better to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling/:

> If you're working on a web application or other software which makes frequent queries you'll want to use a connection pool.

If on the other hand you're writing a script or tool that will have at most one open connection during its runtime, with only a single transaction (or only sequential transactions on the same connection), you can use a single `Client`.